# How to initialize a MessageSource to inject into controller?

Tags: java, groovy, dependency-injection, internationalization, micronaut

I searched the greater half of the internet, but found no clear answer...

I want to do the simple thing: like in Grails have a singleton of `MessageSource` type to use it in a controller for displaying i18n messages.

I want to initialize my `messageSource` from this file(s):

`src/main/resources/my/package/i18n/Messages*.properties`

```
test=FooBar
```

Initialization attempt:

```
class AppConfig {

  @Singleton
  MessageSource messageSource() {
    new ResourceBundleMessageSource( 'my.package.i18n.Messages' )
  }

}
```

The controller to inject to:

```
class CRUDController<T> {

  @Inject
  MessageSource messageSource

  @Transactional( readOnly=true )
  @Get( '/' )
  Map<String,Object> list() {
    log.info "$messageSource -> ${messageSource.getMessage( 'test', MessageSource.MessageContext.DEFAULT )}"
    [:]
  }

}
```

the log info prints this:

> io.micronaut.runtime.context.CompositeMessageSource@79a1d030 -> Optional.empty

so, the messageSource is mis-initialized somehow (and somewhere).

What is the easiest and straight-forward way to do that simple thing?

Comment: Not related to your question but that private constructor is superfluous.

Comment: You will have that even if you delete the private constructor.  The fact that you have another constructor prevents the no-arg constructor from being generated.

Comment: I have pasted your code into a newly created 1.2 app and I can't reproduce the behavior.  If you can point to a sample app which demonstrates the problem it will be easier to diagnose.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown can you paste or point me to the initializing code of `messageSource`?

Comment: "can you paste or point me to the initializing code of messageSource" - It is just what you have... `@Inject MessageSource messageSource`.

Comment: If you can point to a sample app which demonstrates the problem it will be easier to diagnose.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown What I really want to know is how the `messageSource` bean is initialized in the first place. I tried a class with `@Singleton` and a method to return the `ResourceBunldeMessageSource` but it's never invoked. Is the `messageSource` bean managed by Micronaut like in Grails?

Comment: "Is the messageSource bean managed by Micronaut like in Grails?" - All the beans are managed by Micronaut, including the `MessageSource` bean.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown I mean how shall I configure it?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown can you please provide me with or point to a sample, where a `messageSource` is configured using some `basename`?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown see the update pls

Comment: Your code sample does not show `AppConfig` being marked with `@Factory`.  If that is what your real code looks like, that will be part of the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the project at https://github.com/jeffbrown/injecteermessagesource.

https://github.com/jeffbrown/injecteermessagesource/blob/beba0773d41cb475d8d837acc19d0dd41f5b4431/src/main/groovy/injecteermessagesource/CRUDController.groovy

```
package injecteermessagesource

import io.micronaut.context.MessageSource

import javax.inject.Inject

class CRUDController<T> {

    protected final Class<T> clazz

    @Inject
    MessageSource messageSource

    protected CRUDController( Class<T> clazz ) {
        this.clazz = clazz
    }

}
```

https://github.com/jeffbrown/injecteermessagesource/blob/471f6436511c99511426094a8c269112e93149e6/src/main/groovy/injecteermessagesource/PersonController.groovy

```
package injecteermessagesource

import io.micronaut.context.MessageSource
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Controller
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Get

@Controller('/people')
class PersonController  extends CRUDController<Person> {
    protected PersonController() {
        super(Person)
    }

    @Get('/')
    String index() {
        def context = MessageSource.MessageContext.DEFAULT
        def message = messageSource.getMessage('test', context)
        message.get()
    }
}
```

https://github.com/jeffbrown/injecteermessagesource/blob/471f6436511c99511426094a8c269112e93149e6/src/main/groovy/injecteermessagesource/AppConfig.groovy

```
package injecteermessagesource

import io.micronaut.context.MessageSource
import io.micronaut.context.annotation.Bean
import io.micronaut.context.annotation.Factory
import io.micronaut.context.i18n.ResourceBundleMessageSource

@Factory
class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    MessageSource messageSource() {
        new ResourceBundleMessageSource('my.somepackage.i18n.Messages')
    }
}
```

https://github.com/jeffbrown/injecteermessagesource/blob/471f6436511c99511426094a8c269112e93149e6/src/main/resources/my/somepackage/i18n/Messages.properties

```
test=FooBar
```

That all appears to work:

```
$ curl localhost:8080/people
FooBar
```

Comment: I was missing the `@Factory/@Bean` combo only